# NSTable: How to get cell type of column?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

Is it possible to get NSTable's column datatype e.g. ImageCell, TextCell

**Reason**

I have created a function that adds sorting to all columns of an NSTable

```
-(void)addSortingIdentifier:(NSTableView *)table
{
    for (NSTableColumn *tableColumn in table.tableColumns ) {

        ///if column is image cell type then do't go ahead....

        NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:tableColumn.identifier ascending:YES selector:@selector(compare:)];
        [tableColumn setSortDescriptorPrototype:sortDescriptor];
    }

    table.allowsColumnSelection = NO;
}
```

Suppose there is a Image Cell type of column in the NSTable then it will add sorting to it as well.

If user is clicking the column header of image cell type then the sorting of whole NSTable is stopping to work.

**Solution**

I want to make a check in the for loop that if the column type is image cell then do not apply sorting to it.

**Problem**

How to check the type of column?

Answer (score 1):

Here is the flag that You can apply if you want to avoid applying sorting on **NSImageCell**

```
    Class theClass = NSClassFromString(@"NSImageCell"); //getting the class type
    if([[tblClm dataCell] isKindOfClass:theClass]) /// do not apply sorting on image cell class
    {
        continue;
    }
```

**EDIT**

An easy way to compare class type suggested by [Willeke](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4244136/willeke)

```
if([[tblClm dataCell] isKindOfClass:[NSImageCell class]])
....
```

Comment: Why not `isKindOfClass:[NSImageCell class]`?